# How to get the MessageID for individual PubsubMessage to save it in BigQuery for PubsubToBigQuery Event Dataflow Job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I made a PubsubToBigQuery Data flow for storing my Event log by using google templates for the same [PubsubToBigQuery Dataflow Template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java).
I  did some transformation and successfully saved the log to BigQuery. But, I have the requirement of saving the pubsub Message's unique MessageID `(PubsubMessage.getMessageId())` to BigQuery table for some further use-case.
How it can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

To store the MessageID into BigQuery you'd have to preserve this in the DoFn that converts PubsubMessages to Bigtable Rows.

If you want to use this template, it looks like this happens in "ProcessUdf" where [only the payload](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/f62bdc147dc665ceaaf13adb9d984f74c16f75bc/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/common/JavascriptTextTransformer.java#L311) is examined.  You would have to edit this to pass the message id to the javascript UDF as well (or otherwise incorporate it into the returned (json-formatted) result). If you do not need something super generic, it would probably be more efficient and simpler to simply provide a `DoFn<PubsubMessage, TableRow>` and skip all of the json/javascript stuff.